# Is there any tool that does in C#2.0 Automatic winform UI generator from a xml

Tags: user-interface, c#-2.0

I have the following requirement:
In C#2.0, Given a device configuration in xml format and a schema
automatically create a UI displaying the xml.
This ui could change the xml and needs to perform validation on the schema.

I thought of a file defining for each xpath how to display it in UI
(and a default behaviour for unspecified elements).

Is any one aware of existing solutions in C#2.0 producing winform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use XSLT to transform the XML the way you want.  You can transform it to HTML and put the output into a Windows Forms WebBrowser control. Or you could use XSLT to transform your XML + XSD into XAML.

Or, you could use XAML as your XML language, and you don't need your own schema, because you'd be using the XAML schema.

EDIT:  This article - [A Dynamically Generated XML Data Editor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/xmldataeditor.aspx) - on code project sounds closest to what you need.